# Why yum install is giving me this "Could not retrieve mirrorlist" error trying to install a software?

Tags: linux, centos, yum, rpm

I am not a system engineer (I am more a software developer).
I am trying to install Zabbix agent on a CentOS 7 system and I am finding the following problem with yum (I have done the same process on other machines, with success).

First of all I executed this command to install the package:

```
[root@NCMRDB1_COL ~]# rpm -Uvh https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/6.4/rhel/7/x86_64/                                                              zabbix-release-6.4-1.el7.noarch.rpm
Retrieving https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/6.4/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-release-6.4-1                                                              .el7.noarch.rpm
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
Updating / installing...
   1:zabbix-release-6.4-1.el7         ################################# [ 50%]
Cleaning up / removing...
   2:zabbix-release-5.0-1.el7         ################################# [100%]
```

Then I performed this command:

```
    [root@NCMRDB1_COL ~]# yum clean all
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
    Repodata is over 2 weeks old. Install yum-cron? Or run: yum makecache fast
    Cleaning repos: MongoDB base extras updates zabbix zabbix-non-supported
    Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors
```

I think that it simply delete things from yum cache but I see that there are some reference to Zabbix so I do not know if here it is a problem...I suppose that it can be the cause of the problem that I have in the next step.

Finally I execute this command:

```
[root@NCMRDB1_COL ~]# yum install zabbix-agent2 zabbix-agent2-plugin-*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Determining fastest mirrors
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_6                                                              4&repo=os&infra=stock error was
12: Timeout on http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra                                                              =stock: (28, 'Resolving timed out after 30540 milliseconds')


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64
```

Obtaining the error that you can see. What it exactly means? What can I do to fix it and correctly installed my zabbix agent as I previously and succesfully done on the other machines? I suppose that the problem is in the step 2.

Thank you

Comment: Please include the output of `yum repolist enabled`.